# OHow can I extract text from a specific area of an image with python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I am trying to extract text from an image, but within a certain area of the image and not the entire image.

I have already been able to detect where the objects of interest are and get their coordinates. Though I do not know where to start when extracting text from a specific area.

I'm using the code from this example:
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/38470/how-to-detect-circles-in-images

It is able to detect the circles, but I want to take it one step further and extract the numbers from the circles and tag them to their corresponding coordinate.

I'm using this example to learn how to do something similar myself, but I'm really more interested in deciding the search in a set area.

Comment: Kindly share your code and images... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Most image processing libraries support the concept of ROIs (region of interest) or AOIs (area of interest).

The idea is to restrict processing to a subset of pixels that are usually selected by defining geometric shapes like rectangles, polygons, circles within the image coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by first cropping the image using your coordinates and try to extract text from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).